# Calculating a pooled estimate

Tags: meta-analysis, sensitivity-specificity

I am writing a systematic review on certain imaging studies and I was hoping to add a meta-analysis of the sensitivities of the various modalities reported on. My goal was to put together a forest plot a calculate the pooled sensitivity for the different subgroups of methods. However, most of the studies that met the inclusion criteria for review only report a sensitivity and positive predictive value, without confidence intervals for either. My understanding is that, at the very minimum, I need confidence intervals to do a valid pooling, but I was wondering if anyone had any insights about other methods for pooling data that might help me work around this issue?